# How to set a small image on a uiimage view on a particular position?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiview

I created an UIView. 
I need to set a small image on a particular position.

I can do it setting the image in a small separate view.
But, I plan to do it dynamically on a Large UIView which is full screen.
Thanks.

Comment: Did any of the solutions below work for you? If so, please approve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,200)];
view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:view];
// add image in view
UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,20,20)];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[view addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

That is what views are for: manipulating UI widgets.
By far, your best approach is to position a `UIImageView`.

You can also override the view drawing methods:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Curstom
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"];
  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

  //specify the frame of the imageView in the superview , here it will fill the superview
 imageView.frame = catView.bounds;

 // set custom frame as per your requirement

 //or
// imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,30,30); 
//or      
//according to superviews frame
   //imageView.frame=CGRectMake(10,10,yourUIViewObject.bounds.size.width/2,yourUIViewObject.bounds.size.height/2); 

 // add the imageview to the superview
[yourUIViewObject addSubview:imageView];
```